# Amazon EC2 + DNS confusion

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, amazon-ec2

I registered a domain name abc.com with godaddy.com and I am hosting a website in Amazon EC2 with Elastic IP 100.0.0.1

Right now I am forwarding the request to abc.com to ip 100.0.0.1 (browser returns 301)

I want to skip the forwarding part entirely, meaning I want the request to abc.com to hit 100.0.0.1 immediately.

Does this mean I have to setup a DNS (bind9) which has the record that maps abc.com <-> 100.0.0.1 ?

Or is there easier ways to do this (in Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes -- This is the canonical use of DNS. At your DNS provider, create an `A` record that maps abc.com to 100.0.0.1. e.g.:

```
abc.com. 43200 IN A 100.0.0.1
```

Unless you are running the authoritative nameserver for your domain, this will be managed through a control panel of some sort, otherwise, you will configure BIND yourself (outside the scope of this answer).

Alternatively, you can use the `/etc/hosts` file on your machine for a temporary fix (while DNS is changed and propagated, as your local DNS server has likely already cached this record).

```
# /etc/hosts
100.0.0.1    abc.com alias.for.abc.com another-alias
```

and so on and so forth.

Comment: right, there is a control panel where I can specifiy things.